# regex that checks if the string starts with two upper-case followed by numbers

Tags: regex

Hi Guys I need a regex that checks if the string *starts* with *two upper-case* followed by *numbers*:

Example: `DE123456789`

Thanx a lot of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally:

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d+
```

1. `^` - start of the string
2. `[A-Z]` - an upper case letter
3. `{2}` - two of those
4. `\d` - a digit
5. `+` - one or more of those