# Check if the numbers start with two capital letters

Tags: regex

I know there are similar question asked (might the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038690/regex-that-checks-if-the-string-starts-with-two-upper-case-followed-by-numbers)) but I can't seems to get my regex to work. I tried the answer there but didn't work which is below.

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d+
```

I'm trying to check if the country serial or organisation numbers start with specific two capital letters. For example BE0462427110 is from a Belgium company so all the org. numbers should start with BE. German once have DE and Italian once have IT in front.

So I tried below my own version as well.

```
^([BE]{2})([\d]{6,10})$
```

Below is a test block I use to extract the numbers from using regex. And the number is after "BEPC0 PARTS".

> C0MMUNAUTE EUR0PEENNE 1 ExpCd1teur/Exp0rtateur (2) N0. BEPC0 PARTS
> BE0462427110 Rue Chaum0nt(Herm) 4 D F BE 4480 Eng1s E  D q 1jj -
> Dest1na1re (8) N0, N M BUCHER 1ANDTECHN1K SA 7

After the above regex didn't work I tried another.

```
^([B][E])([\d]{6,10})$
```

So what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This anchors at the beginning and end of the string:

```
^([A-Z]{2})([\d]{6,10})$
```

You are looking for a pattern somewhere within a string, so you can anchor by word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b([A-Z]{2})([\d]{6,10})\b
```

Comment: So using ^ and $ only going to effect if the string is a exact match ?

Comment: Yes, from start to end

Comment: Oh ... did not know that. Basically I didn't understand that how it worked. Thank you then this question is done. Will accept when SO allows me to do that. Thank you.